# mysql_connect() shows error in php5

Tags: php

I have using php5-mysql system-Ubantu 13.10, I setup my project but when i login for my first page it give me [:error] [pid 16033] [client 127.0.0.1:53154] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /var/www/Scada/Fleet/phpcmd/login.php on line 29, can you please tell me how I can make my environment compatible to work with the code.

Comment: don't use *mysql_* functions use **mysqli_** or **PDO** instead

Comment: It's exactly like the error says.

Comment: The question already has an answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Comment: I use mysqli_connect() but its not work. Please tell me how I chnage my environment compatible please...

Comment: "it does not work". How are we supposed to know what doesn't work? Does your server explode? Does your browser crash? Can it not reboot? Do you get a PHP error? A PHP notice? What error? What notice? See if you can figure out what's wrong with my car, using this description: "my car does not work. Please tell me how I can fix it please"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Answer (score 3):

change Line 29 `/var/www/Scada/Fleet/phpcmd/login.php on line 29`

from  `mysql_connect()` to  `mysqli_connect()`

you have to change all mysql statements to mysqli statements to get it work.
Or you use PDO.

Answer (score -2):

Do

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

in your index.php or the first line of /var/www/Scada/Fleet/phpcmd/login.php

or use mysqli or PDO instead of the old mysql extensions.

Comment: When he is not the developer of that tool, why should he fix all the code? He just wanted to have a working environment.

Comment: Or research a better tool

Comment: I used mysqli_onnect(); but its give me error. why?